# Strapi crashes when using VK provider

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

Here's the log from console:

```
\my-project\node_modules\strapi-plugin-users-permissions\services\Providers.js:356
              username: `${body.response[0].last_name} ${body.response[0].first_name}`,
                                        ^

TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at vk.query.get.auth.qs.request (C:\Users\Andrele\Desktop\valorant\my-project\node_modules\strapi-plugin-users-permissions\services\Providers.js:356:41)
    at Request._callback (C:\Users\Andrele\Desktop\valorant\my-project\node_modules\purest\lib\transform.js:73:5)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\Andrele\Desktop\valorant\my-project\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Request.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andrele\Desktop\valorant\my-project\node_modules\request\request.js:1154:10)
    at Request.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Andrele\Desktop\valorant\my-project\node_modules\request\request.js:1076:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:203:15)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1145:12)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
```

I configured the provider according to their github tutorial. On first try there was a "connect" window, but now it just crashes with this error. Anything im doing wrong?

Comment: It says that `body.response` is undefined, try `console.log` of `body` and see what the response is. Also, you might want to include your code, too. :)

Comment: I haven't touched the code, so its a default strapi's setup. Console.log of body returns undefined

Comment: Google's auth works just fine, only VK's fails to work

Comment: Based on [Provider.js](https://github.com/strapi/strapi/blob/master/packages/strapi-plugin-users-permissions/services/Providers.js#L355) you might have problems with the config for VK or the access token you are giving the lib?

Comment: On first login it was showing my app and asking for permissions, but after i clicked it crashed. Now it doesnt even ask, but tokens and ids should be fine since it was showing my app correctly

Comment: It doesn't ask, because you already gave permission. Go to VK, Settings and disconnect your app from your profile & try again.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, i couldn't disconnect my app, but i created a new one, it also asked for permissions, but it returned `timeout no token`. After that i tried again and it just crashes the app as usual, same on build and develop